# jQuery my enter doesn't work on new called elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, haml, jquery-events

When new fields are being produced by jQuery, the new fields doesn't work with 'enter'.

This is my script:

coffee

```
$('.teaser-form').keyup (e) ->
  if e.keyCode == 13
    $('.add-new-list').click()
```

form.haml

```
= f.simple_fields_for :products do |p|
  = render 'product_fields', :f => p 
.gear-item-add
  = link_to_add_association 'add item', f, :gears, class: "btn btn-default add-new-list"
```

So the jQuery calls onto the `link_to_add_association` button which creates the fields shown below. (the first field is the initial, so if I press enter, second field and third field is produced... but if I try to go on the third field and press enter, nothing happens)

_product_field.haml

```
.nested-fields.gear-patrol
  .col-md-12
    = f.text_field :list, class: 'teaser-form form-control', placeholder: 'testing'
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements).

Comment: @nnnnnn dang, it looks like it would be the right answer, but I can't figure out how it would work with what I have...

Comment: Find the nearest parent that doesn't change after page load and replace $('.teaser-form').keyup by $('.that_parent_we_are_talking_about').on('keyup', '.teaser-form', function() { // do something here })

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This, Using jQuery

```js
$('body').on('keyup', '.teaser-form', function(e) {

  if (e.keyCode == 13) {

    /* here you can put your code as:
    $('.add-new-list').click()
    */

    var _iDx = $('.teaser-form').length + 1; /*remove this line*/
    $(this).after('<input type="text" class="teaser-form" value="Field ' + _iDx + '">'); /*remove this line*/

    /*keep this code for auto focus to new element*/
    $('.teaser-form').last().focus();

  };

});
```

```css
.teaser-form {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #266F6F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="teaser-form" value="Field 1">
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 5):

As you were looking for CoffeeScript and haml, try this in your code :

```
$(document).on 'keyup', '.teaser-form', (e) ->
  if e.keyCode == 13
    $('.add-new-list').click()
  return
```

This is how it should work with your code regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements) brought by @nnnnnn

Comment: This answer is the correct way of handling this situation.  The jQuery.live() function used to satisfy this need, but has been replaced by jQuery.on() with the document as the target.  The keyup event will then be fired in the document scope, including dynamically added elements.

Comment: the 'on' function may be a bit slower compared to binding new elements tough

Answer (score 0):

**Add the event handlers to *the newly created elements***

re execute this code.

```
$('.teaser-form').keyup (e) ->
  if e.keyCode == 13
    $('.add-new-list').click()
```

Or add the handler to the newly created elements only.

Comment: do you know how event handlers work ? rerun this code AFTER you create new html elements

Comment: I did in the answer above

Comment: see the highlighted part

Comment: How do I call on to the newly created elements, I guess that's what I'm ask... When I'm focused on the input field, and then press enter, how do I use jQuery to focus on the new input fields and be able to press enter?

Answer (score 0):

When you bind a handler to a class it looks for all *existing* objects with that class and binds the logic -- so newly-created objects won't have the handler, whether or not they have the class. This is [maazzaa's point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32162161/3186088).